# Taylor’s theorem with the Lagrange form of the remainder (how to get that last term?)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

[Based upon this reply](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/#comment-176951)

"It is clear that there exist a real $M$ so that

$$f\left(b\right) = f\left(a\right) + f'\left(a\right) \left(b -a\right) + \frac{f''\left(a\right)}{2!}\left(b-a\right)^2 + \cdots + \frac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(a\right)}{n!} \left(b-a\right)^n+ M \left(b-a\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}$$ Now consider the function $$g\left(x\right) = f\left(b\right) – \left[ f\left(x\right) + f'\left(x\right) \left(b -x\right) + \frac{f''\left(x\right)}{2!}\left(b-x\right)^2 + \cdots + \frac{ f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x\right)}{n!} \left(b-x\right)^n + M \left(b-x\right)^{\left(n+1\right)} \right]$$ Applying Rolle’s theorem on the function $g\left(x\right)$ gives directly Lagrange’s form of the remainder: $g\left(a\right) = g\left(b\right) =0$, and almost all terms cancel in the calculation of $g'\left(x\right)$"

---

My question is what's so clear about that last term? **If we didn't already have it explicitly stated, how would think to add it in** *in that form*

I understand that there will be a difference between the Taylor polynomial and the function itself, but why does it have that form of $M\left(b-a\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}$?

If I had to label each part, is this what I'd get:

- $f\left(b\right)$ is function at $b$
- all on right side of equal sign (except for last) is $n$th-degree Taylor polynomial centered at $a$
- last term is the difference between the Taylor series approximation at $B$ and the actual function at $B$ (and so, when combined with the Taylor polynomial, it  fixes that difference)

[image]

Why couldn't we just have $M$ by itself?

I suppose if it was $M\left(b-a\right)$ with $b-a$ to a degree of $n$ or lower then it that coefficient already be satisfied by the Taylor polynomial. Thus, it would need to have a degree of, at least, $n+1$ and then we can multiply that by $M$

Comment: If $a\neq b$ you can obtain $M$ by simply solving for it: put everything before $M$ to the other side and divide through by $(b-a)^{n+1}$.

Comment: To me the most straightforward way to discover an expression for the remainder is to repeatedly use the fundamental theorem of calculus, as follows: $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(s_1) \, ds_1 = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(a)  + \int_a^{s_1} f''(s_2) \, ds_2 \, ds_1 = f(a) + f'(a) ( x - a) + \underbrace{\int_a^x \int_a^{s_1} f''(s_2) \, ds_2 ds_1}_{\text{remainder}}$. You see the pattern. Now we have an expression for the remainder, at least. This is not yet the Lagrange form, but with various manipulations the remainder can be put into various forms.

Comment: I would guess that the elegant proof that you are trying to understand was only thought of later, with the benefit of hindsight, after the Lagrange form of the remainder was already discovered by other means. Once we know (from other lines of investigation) what form the remainder should have, then we might think of expressing the remainder as $M(b - a)^{n+1}$. I don't think the author is claiming that it's clear the remainder *should be* expressed in that form. It's only clear that it *can be* expressed in that form.

Comment: @littleO I know that Stewart's calculus has this addition: https://www.stewartcalculus.com/_update/media/common/6et_at_02_frtts.pdf and so one could prove the remainder the FTC way. And I suppose that once one knows what the remainder is from that proof, then one could formulate another proof which is much easier.

Comment: @Sat Yes, that's how I imagine these ideas might have been discovered. Some thought process like that.

Comment: In question of mine on the same topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021750/ there might be a way to develop the remainder term through induction with the mean value theorem without having to go into FTC and integration